# Why doesn't python3.x have `end="\n"` for fileIO?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, one can do:

```
print("foo bar", end="\n")
```

but not:

```
with open("foo.txt","w") as fout:
  fout.write("foo bar", end="\n")
```

and have to do:

```
with open("foo.txt","w") as fout:
  fout.write("foo bar"+"\n")
```

Is there a reason why? Is there a PEP for this?

Comment: Question should be why `file.writelines()` doesn't add newlines? But its help text days: *Note that newlines are not added.*

Comment: @200OK: the question should be whatever people that *doesn't know the answer* use to formulate it in order for it to be found by people who most need it. Though it is worth to point out the correct terminology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't have anything in particular to do with file i/o; you can use `print()` to print to files just fine:

```
print("foo bar", end="\n", file=fout)
```

The `.write()` method of file objects just writes stuff to the files, it doesn't write lines. `print()`, on the other hand, by default prints a line of output. It needed the `end` argument for those cases when you want to print something that's not a whole line; without it, it couldn't fully replace Python 2's `print` statement, which includes syntax to omit the default newline.

There's no PEP about not including an `end` argument to `.write()`, because writing a PEP to keep a method how it already was in the earliest versions of Python wouldn't make any sense...

Answer (score 3):

The reason is simple, the api to write to a file is meant to be used only to write bytes, not necessarily "lines". Not everything you write to a file is text or should be handled as *lines of text*.

In this sense, you would need to find workarounds when you don't need a `end=`, or explicitly state `end=''`.

In the case of the `print()` function, quite often you are writing to stdout, which most of the times is the terminal where the notion of line is valid.

However there's nothing that prevents you from using `print()` to write to a file by using the `file=` argument.